# Problema al momento de insertar datos de un select en una tabla MySQL

Tags: php, html5, css3, web, php7

mi pregunta va orientado a lo siguiente: lo que pasa es que realicé una consulta a una tabla llamada "Usuarios" específicamente al campo llamado "nombre_completo", el dato de ese campo la cargué en un select, y hasta ahí todo se realiza perfecto. Pero luego, ese mismo dato que cargue en en el select, lo quise almacenar en otra tabla llamada "Faenas", pero el dato me sale numérico (a veces un 2 o 3) ¿A que se deberá eso? Les dejo el código del select y del registro de datos.

formulario.php

```
<select class="ubicacion" name="trabajador_asignado" id="" required>
                            <option value="">Elegir Trabajador</option>
                            <?php
                                include ("./php/conexion_be.php");
                                $quer = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios");
                                while ($usuar = mysqli_fetch_array($quer)) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $usuar[0] ?>"><?php echo $usuar[1] ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                        </select>
```

form1_faena.php

```
<?php  

include 'conexion_be.php';

    $tipo_personal = $_POST['radiogroup1'];
    $tipo_instalacion = $_POST['radiogroup2'];
    $planta = $_POST['planta'];
    $puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $tipo_trabajo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
    $nombres = $_POST['trabajador_asignado'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO planificacion_faena(tipo_personal, tipo_instalacion, planta, puesto_trabajo, fecha, tipo_trabajo, ubicacion, trabajador_asignado) VALUES('$tipo_personal', '$tipo_instalacion', '$planta', '$puesto', '$fecha', '$tipo_trabajo', '$ubicacion', '$nombre')";

    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

    if ($ejecutar) {
        echo '<script>
                alert("Datos ingresados correctamente");
                window.location = "../formulario.php"
        </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script>
        alert("Error, Inténtalo de nuevo");
        window.location = "../formulario.php";
    </script>';
    }


?>
```

Estos son los nombres pertenecientes a la tabla Usuarios, campo "nombre_completo":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esos mismos nombres, son los que quiero que me aparezcan en el campo "trabajador_asignado" de la tabla faenas, pero como mencioné anteriormente, al insertarlos me salen como númericos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas bien en:

```
<option value="<?php echo $usuar[0] ?>"><?php echo $usuar[1] ?></option>
```

El value que le estás dando a el option es el valor del indice 0 del array $usuar, mientras que para mostrar más adelante el nombre estas haciendo un echo del valor del indice 1.

El value va a ser el valor que envies por post, por lo cual, si quieres que este sea el nombre completo, deberás poner en value también el indice 1.

```
<option value="<?php echo $usuar[1] ?>"><?php echo $usuar[1] ?></option>
```